# how to back-up all databases in postgresql iteratively?

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-dump, windows-10

I have a large number of databases in postgresql 9.5 which I want to back-up using pg_dump tool. Each back-up should get its name from the corresponding database.

when I run

```
SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate=false and datname!='postgres';
```

in a psql terminal, it displays all the database names correctly. My issue now is how to use it in pg_dump inside a loop (if required,in a batch script) such that each database is backed up with its corresponding name.

Something like this:

```
FOR %%d IN ("SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE datistemplate=false and datname!='postgres'") DO(
    
    %pgdump% %%d -f %%d.backup
)
```

when I run this, nothing happens.

I am using windows 10 and I'd greatly appreciate any help/hint. Thank you.

Comment: Did you have a chance to do any troubleshooting, like maybe `echo`ing the command you generate to see if it looks right? Also, I don't believe this statement is true: "when I run this, nothing happens". _Something_ surely happens, so you might want to describe, what exactly.

Comment: thanks @mustaccio for your comment....what I meant was, it doesn't produce the desired output and I can't see if there is any error message because the command prompt screen appears for a fraction of a second and disappears....pause & echo also didn't help. I am running the above for loop in a batch script.

Comment: To debug batch files, don't start them with a double click. Open a `cmd.exe` and start it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a Windows question, than a Postgres question. But the following works for me:

```
psql -U postgres -c "\copy (SELECT datname FROM pg_database WHERE NOT datistemplate and datname not in ('postgres')) to dblist.txt"

for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%i in (dblist.txt) do (
  pg_dump -U postgres -Fc --file=%%i.pgdump %%i
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @a_horse_with_no_name .....that worked like a charm...really appreciate it...Also thanks for the hint on running batch from command prompt....